# Is there a version of jQuery somewhere that I can hotlink to without hosting the file?

Tags: jquery, cdn, google-code, hotlinking

Just wondering if there's a website out there that allows you to hotlink to the latest version of jquery. Does Google code allow you, or does jQuery.com itself?

What I'm *not* looking for is a site that just happens to have jQuery that I can pinch. I want a site that says that you can hotlink to their jQuery.

Comment: A few sites do this. You'll want to search for hosted jQuery http://www.google.ca/search?q=hosted+jQuery

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it's available on Google's CDN.

Everything you need is here: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

You can link directly to the javascript file: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

or use the [`google.load`](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/) method

---

**Update**

Its also available on [Microsoft's CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDN.ashx) or the [jQuery CDN](http://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: The Google code link is broken, Google seems to have moved it to a different URL.

Comment: Fun update: the cert for https://code.jquery.com expired today, so a lot of people hotlinking from there are having site problems.

Answer (score 10):

You can have google host it in 1 of 2 methods.

**Method 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",
  //  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the 
  //  latest version matching that partial revision pattern 
  //  (i.e. both 1 and 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today).
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
  });
</script>
```

**Method 2** (more common)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I know jquery.com host's the file as well for users, they might have redirected there jquery hosting to use the google version though.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft is now hosting jQuery as well: http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/#4

Answer (score 3):

In addition to JQuery, Google CDN also hosts JQueryUI and all the default Themeroller CSS UI themes (including images!).  If you're planning to build a UI from JQuery this is pretty clutch.

http://encosia.com/2009/10/11/do-you-know-about-this-undocumented-google-cdn-feature/

Answer (score 2):

Google hosts jquery for you.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery

Answer (score 2):

jQuery now allows you to use their site, as their [download page suggests](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js